# erlang io:format, and a hanging web application

Tags: erlang

While I'm learning a new language, I'll typically put lots of silly println's to see what values are where at specific times.  It usually suffices because the languages typically have available a tostring equivalent.  In trying that same approach with erlang, my webapp just "hangs" when there's a value attempted to be printed that's not a list.  This happens when variable being printed is a tuple instead of a list.  There's no error, exception, nothing... just doesn't respond.  Now, I'm muddling through by being careful about what I'm writing out and as I learn more, things are getting better.  But I wonder, is there a way to more reliably to [blindly] print a value to stdout?
Thanks,

--tim

Comment: Keep in mind also that since Erlang variables are static symbols, you don't need to check up on them. This is why Roberto Aloi says that tracing is more effective. Try writing code so that shocking database returns in the middle of a function don't trip you up also; separate the data collection tasks and the data processing tasks so that the output of collection is the full input to processing and you can always know what is going on, even with crazy inputs from the db.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In Erlang, as in other languages, you can print your variables, no matter if they are a list, a tuple or anything else.

My feeling is that, for printing, you're doing something like (just a guess):

```
io:format("The value is: ~p.", A).
```

This is wrong, because you're supposed to pass a list of arguments:

```
io:format("The value is: ~p.", [A]).
```

Where A can be anything.

I usually find comfortable to use:

```
erlang:display/1
```

to print variables.

Also, tracing functions is usually a better way to debug an application, rather than using printouts. Please see:

http://aloiroberto.wordpress.com/2009/02/23/tracing-erlang-functions/

Answer (score 2):

When developing webapps I use the [error_logger module](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/error_logger.html)
I usually define some macros like this

```
-ifdef(debug).
-define(idbg(FmtStr, Err), 
        error_logger:info_msg("~p (line ~p): " FmtStr "~n", 
                              [?MODULE, ?LINE | Err])).
-define(rdbg(Term), error_logger:info_report(Term)).
-else.
-define(idbg(_FmtStr, _Err), void).
-define(rdbg(_Term), void).
-endif.
```

You call the macros with something like:

```
code...
?rdbg(ErlangTerm),
other code...
```

During development you compile your modules with:

```
erlc -Ddebug *.erl
```

and so you get info messages in your erlang console.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure that there is no terminating process without link which could then cause other process to wait on something and not timeout-ing - hence strange hanging part.